# Convert bytearray to array.array('B')

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an image data, which primarily looks like:

```
array('B', [255,216,255...])
```

It is of type `array.array('B')`

Since this data is to be sent over a communication channel, It is necessary to convert this data to type: `bytearray`.

I converted the data to bytearray:

```
data1 = bytearray(CompressedImage.data)
```

However, I now need to get the original `array.array('B')` form of the data.

So far, I found [`byte()` and `decode()`](https://www.w3resource.com/python/python-bytes.php) function,s but I am still unable to deserialize the original data form.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encoding/decoding is not needed since we are dealing with raw bytes here.

You can pass the bytearray directly to array initializer. You'll still need to specify the type code in the initializer, since the raw bytes themselves can't tell you. "B" for 1 byte unsigned int, i.e. 8-bit colour depth.

```
>>> from array import array
>>> a = array("B", [255, 216, 255])
>>> data1 = bytearray(a)
>>> a1 = array("B", data1)
>>> a1 == a
True
```

If you have an existing array instance to populate, you can use `frombytes`

```
>>> a2 = array("B")
>>> a2.frombytes(data1)
>>> a == a1 == a2
True
```