# Python array.frombytes can't read byte object

Tags: python

This snipped thorws an error, I couldn't find a solution so far.

```
from array import array
arr = array('B',[8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2])
ab = arr.tobytes()
array.frombytes(ab)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[117], line 4
      2 arr = array('B',[8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2])
      3 ab = arr.tobytes()
----> 4 array.frombytes(ab)

TypeError: descriptor 'frombytes' for 'array.array' objects doesn't apply to a 'bytes' object
```

I treid this in Python 3.10.8 and a fresh 3.11.0 environment. No luck with neither

Comment: The `frombytes` method defined in the `array` class is an ordinary instance method, **not** a `classmethod` or `staticmethod`. It needs to be called on an instance of the class. Calling it from the class itself like this means that `ab` will be used as `self`, which doesn't work. The linked duplicate is the most popular I could find on this theme; I will keep looking for a more general canonical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytearray to array.array('B')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746962/convert-bytearray-to-array-arrayb)

Comment: Thank you both. @KarlKnechtel, yes, this is exactly the problem. Corralien's solution, by first building a new array of the same type and then using the method, works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build another array before receive data `frombytes`:

```
from array import array
arr = array('B',[8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2])
ab = arr.tobytes()

arr1 = array('B')
arr1.frombytes(ab)
```

Output:

```
>>> arr1
array('B', [8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2])
```